# Column not found error message in java swing

Tags: java, swing, ms-access

These are my codes inside the .entity directory.

```
    public boolean createUser() {
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "INSERT INTO forumUsers(users_userName,users_password,users_NRIC)";
    sql += "VALUES ('" + userName + "','" + pwd + "','" + nric + "')";
    System.out.println(sql);
    if (db.updateRequest(sql) == 1)
        success = true;
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}

    public boolean retrieveUser() {
    boolean success = false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM forumUsers WHERE users_userName = '";
    dbQuery += userName + "'";
    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
            pwd = rs.getString("password");
            success = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

These are my codes in the user interface class.

```
    if (userName.equals("")||pwd.equals("")||nric.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter all text field");
    else{
        eForumUser user = new eForumUser (userName,pwd,nric);
        if (user.retrieveUser())
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User already exists! Cannot create.");
        else{
            if (user.createUser()==true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User record created successfull!");
        }
```

My database table got users_userName, users_password, users_NRIC, users_securityQuestion, users_answer column.

I can create a data into the database. However, when I try to check whether the username is exist or not by using the retrieveUser method, the console showed me "column not found" error message. So what am I supposed to do to fix this problem? Is it something wrong with my retrieveUser method?

I editted my retriveUser method to:

```
    public boolean retrieveUser() {
    boolean success = false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM forumUsers WHERE users_NRIC AND users_securityQuestion AND users_answer = '";
    dbQuery += userName + securityQuestion + answer + "'";
    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
            pwd = rs.getString("users_password");
            success = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

And I try to retrieve password by entering nric, security question and answer. Here is the code for user interface.

```
    public void submitForgotPwd(ActionEvent e){
    String nric = jTextField.getText();
    Object securityQuestion = jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String answer = jTextField1.getText();
    if (nric.equals("")||securityQuestion.equals("")||answer.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter nric,security question and answer.");
    }else{
        eForumUser user = new eForumUser(nric,securityQuestion,answer);
        if (user.retrieveUser()==true){
        jTextField2.setText(user.getPwd());
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Nric do not exist or wrong security question and answer");
        }
    }
}
```

However, my retrieve does not works. Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Can somebody help me with the second part? I mean the retrieveUser after I edited. It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
pwd = rs.getString("password");
```

the column name is users_password

so change it to

```
 pwd = rs.getString("users_password");
```